# Create Matplotlib line chart with multiple lines and legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is my first post.  I'm trying to plot a single line chart with a line for each 'Subject' in my data frame. The x-axis is column 'Visit Number' and the y-axis is column 'dB'.  I also want a legend.  Data looks like this:

[Data for 4 subjects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xbcK.png)

However, I'm only able to make it work if my data frame contains only one subject:

[Data for one subject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKkLM.png)

```
plt.plot(test_df['Visit Number'], test_df['dB'], 'b-')
plt.show()
```

[Plot for one subject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d62DB.png)

I want a single plot with a line for each subject.  I also want each subject to appear as a label in the legend.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With pandas you can iterate on grouped values, so I suggest you iterate subdatasets and plot each with a label, then call `plt.legend()`.

Here is code I didn't fully test, so use with caution, and maybe consider giving a usable sample of your dataset next time, its easier!

```
for subject, sub_df in testdf.groupby(by='subject'):
    plt.plot(sub_df['Visit Number'], sub_df['dB'], label=subject)
plt.legend()
```